# How $H \cap P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I recently came across the following problem :

> True or false: If $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of a finite group $G$, then for any subgroup $H$ of $G$, $H \cap P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$.

The statement is false. For, take $G=S_3$ ,$P=\{e,(13)\}$  and $H=\{e,(12)\}$. Note that $P$ is the Sylow $2$-subgroup of $G$. Here $$H \cap P=\{e\}$$   but $\{e\}$ is not a Sylow $2$-Sylow subgroup of $H$.

Am I correct? What is the importance of this(true/false) statement if any ?Any help?

Comment: You are correct. The importance of the statement is that if you get it wrong, you fail your Group Theory course. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even a more general fact holds true:

> If $G$ is a finite group, $H \lhd \lhd G$ (subnormal) and $P \in Syl_p(G)$, then $H \cap P \in Syl_p(H)$.

**Proof** Since $H \lhd \lhd G$, we can find a subnormal series: $H=H_0 \lhd H_1 \cdots \lhd H_i \lhd \cdots \lhd G=H_r$. Since $H_{r-1} \lhd G$, $P \cap H_{r-1} \in Syl_p(H_{r-1})$. But $H_{r-2} \lhd H_{r-1}$, so $P \cap H_{r-1} \cap H_{r-2}=P \cap H_{r-2} \in Syl_p(H_{r-2})$. Now induction finishes the proof.

Comment: Thanks!..........

Answer (score 2):

I searched the results relating to this and I found the following one:

> Let G be a finite group, $H \triangleleft G$ be a normal subgroup and $P$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. Then  $H \cap P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$ and its proof is found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2060974/let-g-be-a-finite-group-h-triangleleft-g-be-a-normal-subgroup-and-s-be-a-s).

So the answer for my question " What is the importance of this result if any " is $$\text{when $H$ is normal, then the statement in the OP is true!} $$
   That is, normality is essential in the hypothesis of H