# Let $G$ be a finite group, $H◃G$ is a normal subgroup, $S$ is a Sylow subgroup of $G$. Show that $H \cap S$ is a Sylow subgroup of $H$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

I'm trying to work on the proofs presented for this question: [Let G be a finite group, $H \triangleleft G$ be a normal subgroup and $S$ be a Sylow subgroup of $G$. Show that $H \cap S$ is a Sylow subgroup of $H$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2060974/let-g-be-a-finite-group-h-triangleleft-g-be-a-normal-subgroup-and-s-be-a-s)

There are multiple proofs presented with conjugation etc. But i don't understand why the following, simple argumentation wouldn't suffice:

> $S$ contains all elements of order $p^n$ by Sylow theorems. So the intersection of $H \cap S$ also will contain elements of orders  $p^n$ up to a certain $n$. However, the maximum integer $n$ which can be taken as a $p$-subgroup here will be limited by $p^n \le |H|$. If $n$ is not maximal, then $H \cap S$ contains a larger subgroup of prime power $p^k, k \gt n$. (this last claim im unsure of). So $H \cap S$ is a sylow $p$ subgroup of $H.$

Comment: I agree that the claim you single out is not justified. Indeed, this proof never uses the hypothesis that $H$ is normal in $G$. So I suspect a counterexample to that claim can be found using counterexamples to the overall statement if $H$ is not required to be normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proof: $K=HS$ is a subgroup of $G$ since $H$ is normal, $S$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $K$. The order of $K$ is $|H||S|/|H\cap S|$. Therefore $|H:H\cap S|$ is not divisible by $p$. On the other hand $H\cap S$ is a $p$-group by Lagrange. Hence $H\cap S$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$.

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you